# How to get actual calculation value from airthmatic operation

Tags: java, calculator

I have this code:

```
float result = (85000/12)*5;
System.out.println(result );
```

the value of `result`  is coming **35415.0** but the actual calculation `result` is **35416.66** .

I tried all data types but didn't get actual value. how should i get it.

Comment: Try using `float result = (85000/12.0)*5`

Comment: thanks avidProgrammer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(85000 / 12) * 5`; is evaluated as you see it: `85000 / 12` is evaluated in *integer arithmetic* - the remainder is discarded. The result of that is multiplied by `5`.

To retain the `float` type of the compile time evaluable constant expression, use `85000f / 12 * 5`.

I always promote the first coefficient, (i) for clarity, (ii) because something like `85000 / 12 * 5f` will exhibit truncation effects.

Comment: You need to change the type to double too

Comment: `85000.0 / 12 * 5` wont compile as float but `85000f / 12 * 5` is the right answer

Comment: thanks Dogukan Zengin. u r right